# Which Stack Exchange site would be fit to ask a question related to Blogger

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask question about Blogger. The Blogger site is https://www.blogger.com/. Here I am not able to format the code while writing my post.
Which Stack Exchange site would be suitable to ask this question?

Comment: It depends what you want to ask exactly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I have written, I am unable to format code while making article.

Comment: If you mean you tried writing a blog and got error, no SE site is fitting. Look for blogger.com support forum and write there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about Blogger are on-topic on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) .
They have a tag for the subject: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger .

There are a number of questions about formatting on Blogger already, so *first* check if your question is already answered there.

If not, you can post the question there, providing as much information as is necessary for a good answer.

When asking, be sure to show what you have tried, it can make a lot of difference in the votes that you get!!